# Python: Como buscar a data atual

Tags: python

Estou tentando buscar alguns arquivos de uma pasta que trás um padrão no nome do arquivo, no caso é 3067-EG3067000076 mais a data, porém como serão arquivos diários a data muda diariamente e também existe outro porém, como a data de quando baixo o arquivo vem do dia anterior preciso voltar um dia (por isso o day=1) e quando o arquivo é baixado na segunda feira preciso voltar 3 dias por isso o (days=3) pensando nessas variantes desenvolvi esse código, de primeiro momento ele funcionou mas agora não funciona mais, alguém teria uma sugestão de qual função usar para a data? ou uma sugestão de código?

```
import os
import calendar
from datetime import date
from pathlib import Path

data_atual = calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]
    
if data_atual == 'Monday':
    teste= 'true'
else: 
    teste= 'false'

if teste == 'true':
    data_atual = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    data_atual = (data_atual.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
else:
    data_atual = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    data_atual = (data_atual.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
    
os.rename(r'C:\Users\joao\Desktop\convenios\3067-EG3067000076' + str(data_atual) + '.CNV',r'C:\Users\joao\Desktop\convenios2\arquivo.CNV')
```

O código gera esse erro:

> NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in  4 from pathlib import Path
> 5 ----> 6 data_atual = calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()] 7 8 if
> data_atual == 'Monday': NameError: name 'my_date' is not defined

Comment: Qual é resultado obtido?

Comment: A primeira vez que testei funcionou, agora apresenta esse erro.  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-dae84386bf9f> in <module>
      4 from pathlib import Path
      5 
----> 6 data_atual = calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]
      7 
      8 if data_atual == 'Monday':

NameError: name 'my_date' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua lógica está correta, mas há coisas esquisitas no seu código.

```py
data_atual = calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]
    
if data_atual == 'Monday':
    teste= 'true'
else: 
    teste= 'false'
```

1. Na primeira linha do trecho de código, você faz `my_date.weekday()`, mas o objeto `my_date` nunca foi definido, ocasionando o erro que você citou nos comentários. Você comentou que "a primeira vez funcionou", mas provavelmente era outro código. Esse não funcionará nunca [exceto se existe código antes disso que não colocou na pergunta].
2. Não faz sentido você fazer `teste = 'true'`. Uma que o nome de variável `teste` é péssimo e não remete a nada o que a variável representa. Segundo que no Python existe o tipo booleano para esses casos, representados pelos valores `True` e `False`. Não há porque criar uma string para isso.

Em resumo, o que você precisa é sempre pegar o último dia útil, então você pode simplificar o código:

```py
import datetime


def get_last_business_day():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    delta = max(1, (today.weekday() + 6) % 7 - 3)
    return today - datetime.timedelta(days=delta)
```

Para fins didáticos, chamaremos o valor dentro de `max`, `(today.weekday() + 6) % 7 - 3`, de `x`, para então montarmos a tabela a seguir relacionando o valor de `today.weekday()`, que remete a qual dia da semana estamos com o valor de `x`:

| Dia | `today.weekday()` | `x` | `max(1, x)` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Segunda-feira | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| Terça-feira | 1 | -3 | 1 |
| Quarta-feira | 2 | -2 | 1 |
| Quinta-feira | 3 | -1 | 1 |
| Sexta-feira | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| Sábado | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| Domingo | 6 | 2 | 2 |

> **Nota:** importante salientar que mesmo que no nosso calendário a semana inicia-se no Domingo, no Python o dia zero é a segunda-feira como opção dos criadores da biblioteca simplesmente para facilitar a verificação se é um dia útil ou não (`day.weekday() < 5`)

Desta forma, vemos que se for uma segunda-feira, iremos descontar 3 dias para obter a última sexta-feira; se for domingo, serão 2 dias; se for sábado, um dia; e se for qualquer outro dia, um dia também.

Comment: woss boa noite, primeiramente quero agradecer o auxilio, entendi o seu código porém quando executo no meu jupyter o mesmo não retorna nada, mesmo dando print. Tentei formatar a data para %Y%m%d" e não retorna nada

Comment: @GabrielTerribile você chamou a função?

Comment: Deu certo Woss, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você quer fazer algo do género:

```
import datetime  
import calendar

dataHoje = datetime.datetime.now() #define a data de hoje
diaHoje = (calendar.day_name[dataHoje.weekday()]) #define o dia hoje
print("data: ", dataHoje,"\ndia semana: ", diaHoje ) #apresenta os resultados

x = int(input("Dias a retirar: ")) #escolher dias a voltar atrás

data = datetime.timedelta(days = x) #define os -x dias em formato data
finalData = dataHoje - data #define a data -x
finalDia = calendar.day_name[finalData.weekday()] #define o dia -x
print ("Data: ", finalData, "\nDia: ", finalDia) #Apresenta o resultado
```

Isto vai lhe apresentar a data e dia, basta mudar o input do "x" para a sua variável que retira os dias. Agora, para fazer os "if" basta fazer o seguinte:

```
if (finalDia == "Friday"):
    #Faz aqui o que quiser
```

Nota: O programa retira-me os dias em Inglês, tem de alterar o "if" com base naquilo que retirar no seu computador.

Comment: Show mano, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -1):

Pelo o que pude ver você esta tentando alterar o nome do arquivo de acordo com data do dia, isso pode ser feito através da biblioteca datetime, fica minha recomendação da [leitura](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) pois com essa biblioteca ela retorna data dia horas segundos tudo que você precisa para seu código.

segue um exemplo de como obter a data e incluir no arquivo.

```
makedirs(r'\Solicitações dia {}'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%y')))
```

caso precise de mais informações no link deixado acima existe um tabela com paramentos a ser passado na função.

agora para voltar os dias o retorno do código acima é uma `string` assim você deve converter e talvez criar uma função que volte os dias que você precise:

talvez esse código abaixo possa ajudar no desenvolvimento da logica para sua aplicação:

```
from datetime import datetime

data = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M - %A %d / %B / %Y')


def escrever_datas_por_extenso(data):

    mesesEN =['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
              'November', 'December']

    mesesPT = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro',
               'Novembro', 'Dezembro']

    diasPT = ['Segunda-Feira', 'Terça-Feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-Feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sabado', 'Domingo']

    diasEN = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

datalist = data.split()

datalist[2] = diasPT[diasEN.index(datalist[2])]

datalist[5] = mesesPT[mesesEN.index(datalist[5])]

data = ''

for palavra in datalist:
    data = data + " " + palavra

return data

print(escrever_datas_por_extenso(data))
```

e para voltar as datas basta apenas criar um condição que trabalhe o `index` da data que você quer

Comment: Certo Kelvin, essa é a ideia mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @GabrielTerribile se alguma das respostas atendeu sua solicitação, é um bom costume marcar como correta para as pessoas que tiverem a mesma duvida saber qual resolveu seu problema.

Comment: Show, as 3 de certa forma contribuíram então marquei as 3 :)